# Powershell output messages intertwined with other messages from other sources

Tags: visual-studio, powershell

I basically have something like

```
$outputMsg1="foo`nbla`n"
Write-host $outputMsg1
```

in a Powershell script which I call in Visual Studio 2022 Post Build Event. The script is called more than once, sometimes simultaneously. The result sometimes is

```
foo
foo
bla
bla
```

so the output is interlaced, intertwined. Interestingly enough, the split is never done in the middle of an word.

How can I make Powershell write a message to output in one chunk?

Even better, is it a way to group all the writes in a script in a chunk so even when I have several Write-host statements they are written one after another not interrupted by other messages from another instance of the script or whatever? So as long as a script runs to get exclusive output access.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding all logic into a function and store the function output into a variable, so messages will be grouped:

```
function Do-Stuff{
   Write-Output '1'
   Write-Output '2'
}

$out = Do-Stuff | Out-String 
$out
```

Comment: That won't work, `Write-Host` doesn't return anything, `$out` will be `$null`

Comment: yes, you are correct, they only if he changes write-host with write-output